Both side Scrollable frame for list of button in both direction - Customtkinter
I have frame in a page class where there are 10x10 buttons and entry widgets how to make the frame scrollable in both directions in python tkinter.
Canvas is not working as it i cannot place button on the canvas. Please do help on this regard.

I got it to work using a canvas and placing the buttons there! :)
import customtkinter

# Creating app
app = customtkinter.CTk()
app.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
app.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

# Creating Canvas
canvas1 = customtkinter.CTkCanvas(app, highlightthickness=0)
canvas1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

# Creating Scrollbars
scroll_vertical = customtkinter.CTkScrollbar(app, width=15, command=canvas1.yview)
scroll_vertical.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")

scroll_horizontal = customtkinter.CTkScrollbar(app, height=15, command=canvas1.xview)
scroll_horizontal.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew")

# Linking the scrollbars to the canvas
canvas1.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll_vertical.set)
canvas1.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll_horizontal.set)

# Creating buttons and placing them in the Canvas
button1 = customtkinter.CTkButton(canvas1, text="Hello!")
button1.grid(row=0, column=0)

button2 = customtkinter.CTkButton(canvas1, text="Hello again!")
button2.grid(row=0, column=1)

app.mainloop()


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
